# map values not populating in gsp

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, gsp

I Have the following controller:-

```
class HostController {

def index() {

def customMap = ['key1':'value1','key2':'value2']
[customMap : customMap]
}
```

}

and the following gsp view:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'host.label', default: 'Host')}" />
    <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
<body>

    this is the custom map      
    <g:each in="${customMap.value}" var="custom">
    ${custom}
    </g:each>
</body>
```

I am unable to print thae values of the map.
Although I am able to print the keys using:

```
<g:each in="${customMap}" var="custom">
    ${custom.key}
</g:each>
```

I am not sure what is being missed here.
Any help here is much appreciated.

Thanks,
AMar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your gsp code to:

```
<g:each in="${customMap}" var="custom">
   ${custom.value}
</g:each>
```

You see, `customMap` is a recognized object which you passed from the controller to the view, `customMap.value` is not.